# Sql table Default Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, default-value

Hi everyone i have a project i am working on that consists on keeping tables the same at 3 different locations

i pull data that doesnt exist from each of these locations into a corporate table, i then need to send back down to the locations the new data so they are all the same

The table i am pulling from is a identity

My question is in Sql is there any way to make a table a identity without making it a identity as in setting the default value to be the max(id)+1, this is the only way i can figure i can keep the data structure the same without going to replication

Comment: that's why guid's are superior for keys.

Comment: You could write a trigger to achieve that behavior

Comment: For such like things there is a future in the SQL Sever named replication.

Comment: What is your reason for not wanting to use replication?

Comment: @TMcKeown There are many instances where GUID's aren't superior keys, but this is one area where they would be a good option.

Comment: @TMckeown So guid you mean a unique identifier in sql, are you allowed to insert those records into a table at another location

Comment: @GoatCO sites im working with do not want to use it, the had to many bad experiences

Comment: if the key is a uniqueidentifier then yes you could assign the key.

Comment: the only negative of guids are the length and general obscurity but i have grown to prefer them as they don't have this integration issue with other DB's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're generating records in an `IDENTITY` field in multiple sources, then unable to combine them without those records being assigned new `IDENTITY` values.

By using a `GUID` as your key field, each of the 3 databases can create records which will have a unique ID, and you'll be able to then combine them without issue.   You can still have a `UNIQUE` constraint on the field, but the likelihood of generating the same GUID is astronomically small.

Most replication processes utilize this GUID approach at some level already, so it's a common solution to this problem.

Comment: i will test this out goat i already have a guid on that table, i was using it to keep the data unique, i added the id thinking i could make it assign what i want, give me around 10 minutes and ill know if this will work for me

Comment: thank you goat and TMCkeown, this will work for me for now if i ever do run into duplicates i will think about triggers